# How to fix this strange UnboundLocalError and implement a well working patching function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching

I determined to write a patch decorator as a monkey patch. I thought it would be easy but this code always rises UnboundLocalError while running. Source code here:

```
def patch(source, target):
    def _(func):
        def __():
            print source        # `source` is accessible as I expected
            _target = target    # Error here
            target = source
            func()
            target = _target
        return __
    return _


import os

@patch(patch, os)
def f():
    pass

f()
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    f()
  File "test.py", line 4, in __
    _target = target
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'target' referenced before assignment
```

The variable `target` should also be accessible just as variable `source`, I have not idea why this would rise error.

Comment: Assignment marks names as *local*, so simply having the statement `target =` in the inner function means Python sees it as a local name. You are not altering the closure. You cannot, in fact, assign to a closed-over name like that in Python 2.

Comment: Note that you are also reusing the name `patch`.. `@patch(patch, ...)` passes in `patch` to itself.

Comment: Last but not least, simply setting the name `target` within your decorator to something else *doesn't patch the original object*. You are simply re-binding something within the function, the global outside of the function won't be affected.

Comment: You could do what you wanted by setting `globals()[target.__name__]` (assuming you didn't use a `import module_name as alias`) but altering globals like that is of course not thread-safe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the real goal is completely unclear and attempted solution is simply wrong. Despite I answered the question initially, I consider it as a mistake from my side because simply avoiding the trivial exception won't make this code work. Actually no modification of this code can make it work and a completely different approach has to be taken. However explaining monkey patching in details falls into __too broad__ category.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will do exactly what you want:

```
def patch(source, target):
    t = target
    def _(func):
        def __():
            print source
            _target = t
            target = source
            func()
            target = _target
        return __
    return _


import os

@patch(other_patch, os)
def f():
    pass

f()
```

Comment: No it won't, because nothing is actually being monkeypatched.

Comment: All you do is swapping out *local names*. You won't alter what `f` sees.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's why I've written `I hope` because I don't fully get his idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the things I've solved are: the exception from the question and the name clashing issue with `patch`. If the question was `How do I monkey patch?` I would just vote `Close -> Too broad`

Comment: You answered the exception, but I fear there will be follow-up questions because this is an X-Y problem at heart.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are of course right. Then maybe we should really close the question as it really goes straight to the dead end... ?